# Update a table in hibernate using many-to-many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two POJOs Degree and Course. They are a many-to-many mapping and I use XML to map Degrees to Courses. When creating a Degree it inserts an id, degree name, department and a Java Set of the Course class.

The mapping looks like this:

```
<class name="Degree" table="MY_DEGREES">
    <id name="id" column="DEGREE_ID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <property name="degreeName" unique="true"/>
    <property name="department"/>


<set name="degreeCourses"
    table="DEGREE_COURSE"
    cascade="save-update">
    <key column="DEGREE_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="Course" column="COURSE_ID"/>
</set>
```

It works fine when adding a course that doesn't exist yet, but since I have set Course Names to be unique if I add a Degree with a course name that already exists then it will give me a JDBC BATCH update error and won't add the tables.

I'd like to be able to add a Course in the course table if it's not already there, or add update a Course in the course table if it is there.

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks in advanced

Edit:

This is my course hbm

```
<class name="Course" table="MY_COURSES">
    <id name="id" column="COURSE_ID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <property name="courseName" unique="true"/>
    <property name="subject"/>
    <property name="semester" />
    <property name="capacity" />
    <property name="roomNumber"/>
    <property name="buildingName"/>
    <property name="professor"/>
    <property name="courseDescription"/>
    <property name="credits"/>


</class>
```

This is the full exception printed.

```
Hibernate: select max(COURSE_ID) from MY_COURSES
Hibernate: insert into MY_COURSES (courseName, subject, semester, capacity,     roomNumber, buildingName, professor, courseDescription, credits, COURSE_ID)     values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC     batch update
    at     org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at     org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at     org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at     org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(Abstract    FlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at     org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListe    ner.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at     org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.jamellawson.www.OracleDAO.saveObject(OracleDAO.java:35)
    at com.jamellawson.www.Degree.main(Degree.java:53)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint     (JL.SYS_C005028) violated

    at     oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:34    3)
    at     oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.    java:10657)
    at     org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at     org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: If possible can you please post full exception and queries generated by hibernate and mapping of course?

Comment: I just added more information. Please let me know if that clears anything up for you.